# Replace spring custom form of security by spring security oauth login page

Tags: spring-security-oauth2

How replacement authentication using a custom form in spring security developed by external authentication ( System that handles authenticated) communication between the two systems is performed using Oauth 2. Spring ?

I currently have functional example TONR  of the spring security oauth2 modified to a protected resource application requires external authentication . The problem is that to access the resource have to go through the custom form Springsecurity and land later by the form of the external system.